# How to Pass dynamic ceated table row column Data values from JSP to Spring controller through ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring

I have a dynamic created table which have different column.
I want to take this all data from this JSP and want to pass in Spring.

JSP

```
<body>
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="myTable">
        <tbody>
             <tr id="table1">

              </tr> 
             <tr id="table2">

              </tr> -->
            <tr id="table3">

             </tr> 
         </tbody>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

And the JavaScript ajax call function is

```
function saveSubmit() {

        var selectBox = document.getElementById("selectBozone");
        var buzoneID = selectBox.options[selectBozone.selectedIndex].value;
        var profileName = document.getElementById("profile-title").innerText; 
       //   var tableArray = new Array(); 
            var tableArray = document.getElementById("myTable");

        $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       dataType: " ",
       url: "/lyra/admin/saveProfileBuzoneRights",
       data: "buzoneID=" + buzoneID + "&profileName=" + profileName + "&tableArray=" + tableArray,
       success: function(response) {

       }
        });   

     alert("El proceso se ha realizado correctamente");
     //window.location = "profilesRecord";
 }
```

But In Controller Side i am getting value **Object HTMLTableElement** for tableArray  varible.
That's why i am not able to iterate the value of this variable.
Please help on this.

Comment: You are trying to get a html table element to be represented as an array which it is not. How you would get to the data you need depends on what exactly you want to transmit using the ajax call.
You can get the whole TABLE HTML code by adding myTable.innerHTML to the ajax data, but that doesn't seem like a likely use.
So you would have to extract the data from the table, which is not adequately described in the question. Also, normally you wouldn't want to send static table data through ajax - maybe there are input fields missing from your table.

Answer (score 0):

1)

```
selectBozone.selectedIndex
```

does not exist, but you defined the variable selectBox in the line before that.

```
selectBox.selectedIndex
```

2)

When passing data to the jquery ajax call you should use json notation:

```
data:{name:value,name:value,......}
```

instead of concatenating a request url with &

3)

getElementById() retrieves a TABLE which is a single HTML element and not an array of data.
More information needed on the data needed.